# extract from JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, iterator

```html
"biodata": {
    "Ruby": {
      "Expertise": "web development",
      "EXperience": "5 years"
    },
    "Dylon": {
      "Expertise": "Java",
      "EXperience": "2 years"
    }
 }
```

I have the above JSONObject . I am trying to fetch some keys here .

1. I am looking to fetch the name key i.e Ruby , Dylon etc .
2. I am then trying to fetch the "Experience " key value .

**Desired output :**

name= Ruby
Experience = 5 years

**My code :**

```js
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path to JSON file"));

JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) obj;

String statistics = jsonobj.getString("biodata"); //The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

for (Iterator key = jsonobj.keys(); itr.hasNext();) {//The method keys() is undefined for the type JSONObject //itr cannot be resolved
     JSONObject name = jsonobj.get(key.next()); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject  
     String key = key.next();//The method next() is undefined for the type String
     JSONObject name = jsonobj.get(key); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject
     Log.d("data", "key="+key+ " and value="+jsonobj.toString()); //Log cannot be resolved  
}
```

**I have mentioned the errors in the comment of my code .**

Comment: leave it........

Comment: You can check my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You json is not valid .

You should change to this .

```
{ 
 "biodata": {
    "Ruby": {
      "Expertise": "web development",
      "EXperience": "5 years"
    },
    "Dylon": {
      "Expertise": "Java",
      "EXperience": "2 years"
    }
 }
}
```

Try this .

```
private void jsonParse() {
    try {
        // use jsonobject to parse json with 
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path to JSON file"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        // get jsonobject by biodata tag
        JSONObject biodata = jsonObject.getJSONObject("biodata");
        // use Iterator to get name 
        Iterator<String> names = biodata.keys();
        // use while loop
        while (names.hasNext()) {
            // get name 
            String name = names.next().toString();
            Log.d("data", "name=" + name);
            // get jsonobject by name tag 
            JSONObject nameJsonObject = biodata.getJSONObject(name);
            // get string 
            String Expertise = nameJsonObject.getString("Expertise");
            String EXperience = nameJsonObject.getString("EXperience");
            Log.d("data", "Experience =" + EXperience);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: pardon me , How do I pass JSON  file path here ?

Comment: As per OP I believe you are missing the logic of reading from the file reader

Comment: @mhasan that may be the case right now . Do I need to convert toString()  after I read the file after :                                                                         
 Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path to JSON file"));                         obj.toString();

Comment: I am getting the error : The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined in JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: What may be the reason ?

Comment: @KeLiuyue Thanks a ton . But why is there an error in the log ." Log cannot be resolved"

Comment: You only should import Log.Also you can remove it .

Comment: You can use `System.out.print("name=" + name);
        System.out.print("Experience =" + EXperience);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157709/discussion-between-jane-and-keliuyue).

Comment: @KeLiuyue I have accepted the answer . Thank you . but I have some concerns :

Comment: I am getting a certain error as : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
on line : JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
i have imported : import org.json.simple.*;
still its same error

Comment: Use `JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(obj.toString());` .

Comment: Good luck to you.@jane

Answer (score 1):

You have many issues in your code.

**First**: Assuming you want to implement code based on your current JSON String

Issues:

1. [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) API do not facilitate the methods of Map used in your implementation.
2. Your JSON String is not a array so for loop is not going to help, instead you should fetch the inner JSONObjects using the getJSONObject () method of the JSONObject API.
3. Casting the parsed object from your parser API will not automatically make it a JSONObject, the right way of doing this as below:

   JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(new FileReader("path to JSON file")).getAsJsonObject();

**Second**: Assuming you intent to implement the JSON string representation as array, you should correct your JSON string as below.

```
"biodata": [{ "Ruby": { "Expertise": "web development", "EXperience": "5 years" }}, {"Dylon": { "Expertise": "Java", "EXperience": "2 years" } }]
```

With the above JSON string you can implement the fetching of data logic using [JSONArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) API

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response .

Comment: When I try to read the file as  :   JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(new FileReader("path to JSON file")).getAsJsonObject();   i get the error as : The method getAsJsonObject() is undefined for the type Object